# What is the proper way of manipulating scroll of overflowed flexbox in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Consider the following structure:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Sample Text1, Sample Text2, Sample Text3</p>
</div>
<button onclick="handleScrollLeft()">Left</button>
<button onclick="handleScrollRight()">Right</button>
```

Because I'm working in ReactJS, my real code looks more like this:

```jsx
    export function Slider() {
    
      const handleScrollLeft = () => {
      }
    
      const handleScrollRight = () => {
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className="container">
            <p>Sample Text1, Sample Text2, Sample Text3</p>
          </div>
          <button onClick="handleScrollLeft">Left</button>
          <button onClick="handleScrollRight">Right</button>
        </>
      );
    }
```

With those 2 buttons I would like to change the scroll value (move left and right respectively). I'm not sure how to handle this kind of change:

1. **In useEffect?**  (I don't want to force re-render, just expand the scroll functionality to those 2 buttons)
2. **Create custom hook?**  (Same concern)
3. **Or should I directly modify that DOM element in the handler functions?**  (I know this is a big no-no in React)

I'm really confused on which approach is correct, any advise or solution with further explanation on **why** would be appreciated

Comment: You could use [`element.scrollBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy). It's not really "modifying" DOM, so it shouldn't conflict with React's own logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useRef` hook and the `element.scrollBy` method.

```
const STEP = 40;

export function Slider() {
  const scrollable = useRef(null);
  
  const handleScrollLeft = () => {
    scrollable.current.scrollBy(-STEP, 0);
  }
    
  const handleScrollRight = () => {
    scrollable.current.scrollBy(STEP, 0);
  }
    
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container" ref={scrollable}>
        <p>Sample Text1, Sample Text2, Sample Text3</p>
      </div>

      <button onClick="handleScrollLeft">Left</button>
      <button onClick="handleScrollRight">Right</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can also use this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-kalam-6cghv9?file=/src/App.js) as an example.

Comment: works exactly as I've desired, thanks!